# drawing a plane and orthonormal system using tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, technical-drawing, tikz-arrows

I want to draw the following image and i face problems especially in the plane on the left :

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}    
\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\draw[thick,->] (52,0) -- (60,0) node[anchor=north west] {$x'$}; 
\draw[thick,->] (56,-04) -- (56,04) node[anchor=south east] {$x_N$};
\draw[red,thick,dashed] (56,0) circle (2cm); 
\draw[thick,->] (57.5,1.55) -- (58,2) node[anchor=north west] {$I^{+}(1)$}; 
\draw[thick,->] (57.5,-1.55) -- (58,-2) node[anchor=north west] {$I(1)$}; 
\draw (56,0) node[below right] {$O$} node{$\bullet$}; 
\draw (58,0) node[below right] {$1$} node{}; 
\draw (54,0) node[below left] {$-1$} node{}; 
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

i draw the orthonormal system using the `tikzpicture` and i didn't know how to continue any help?

Comment: post your orthonormal system and we'll take it from there. Welcom to TeX-SX by the way!

Comment: \begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[thick,->]  (52,0) -- (60,0) node[anchor=north west] {$x'$};
\draw[thick,->]  (56,-04) -- (56,04) node[anchor=south east] {$x_N$};
\draw[red,thick,dashed] (56,0) circle (2cm);
\draw[thick,->] (57.5,1.55) -- (58,2)  node[anchor=north west] {$I^{+}(1)$};
\draw[thick,->] (57.5,-1.55) -- (58,-2)  node[anchor=north west] {$I(1)$};
\draw (56,0) node[below right] {$O$} node{$\bullet$};
\draw (58,0) node[below right] {$1$} node{};
\draw (54,0) node[below left] {$-1$} node{};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

Comment: Great! As you can see, instead of pasting as a comment you can edit your own question and include your code by marking it as a code block at the top bar of question tools. It's much easier for us if you complete your example to a compilable example as I did with yours for this time ;) Because then people directly copy paste the existing code and start adding.

Comment: yes it's better but this is the first time i post a tex question  . thank you for your remark i will do that next time.

Answer (score 12):

Here is one attempt using `hobby`.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{hobby,patterns}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[thick,->] (52,0) -- (60,0) node[anchor=north west] {$x'$};
\draw[thick,->] (56,-04) -- (56,04) node[anchor=south east] {$x_N$};
\node[draw=red,dashed,thick,circle,minimum width=4cm] (n) at (56,0) {};
\fill[pattern=north east lines,opacity=.6] (58,0)arc(0:180:2cm) -- (58,0);
\draw[thick,->] (57.5,1.55) -- (58,2) node[anchor=north west] {$I^{+}(1)$};
\draw[thick,->] (57.5,-1.55) -- (58,-2) node[anchor=north west] {$I(1)$};
\draw (56,0) node[below right] {$O$} node{$\bullet$};
\draw (58,0) node[below right] {$1$} node{};
\draw (54,0) node[below left] {$-1$} node{};

\node[draw,circle,minimum width=2cm] (n1) at (50,3) {};
\begin{scope}
\clip[draw](48,1) to[closed,curve through={(50,3) .. (52,4) .. (51,6) ..(47,6) .. (46.6,5) .. (45,3.8) }] (48,1);
\node[draw,circle,fill=magenta,minimum width=2cm] (n1) at (50,3) {};
\end{scope}
\node[inner sep=1pt,fill,circle,label={below right: $x_0$}] at (50,3){};
\draw[->,shorten <= -4mm] (n1.90) -- +(0.7,0.7) node[pos=1.3]{$\Omega_1 \cap \Omega$};
\draw[->] (51,6) -- +(0.7,0.3) node[pos=1.3]{$\Omega$};
\draw[->] (n1.300) -- +(0.7,-0.3) node[pos=1.3]{$\Omega_1$};
\draw[->] (n1.10) to[bend left] node[midway,below]{8*} (n.120);   %% 8* = ???
\node at (50,-1){ Some text???};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Some text content was not clear to me which I have marked with `???` in the code.

Comment: i try it but it give that it can't find "tikzlibraryfile", how i can install it? how i can solve this problem?

Comment: i have the mikteX 2.9 and texmaker in my pc, and i'm getting the following error "I can't find 'tikzlibraryhobby.code.tex'

Comment: i always work with the texmaker, in everything but this is the first time i use this library and get this error.

Comment: we can't draw it using another library? @Harish Kumar

Comment: Ok i can but how to install it from where any ideas?

Comment: in the package manager i can't find hobby package how i can download it? @Harish Kumar

Comment: the "$8^*=\tau*$". i need a favor can you send the image as a pdf to my mail i'm still facing problem to install the hobby package? @Harish Kumar

Comment: makkiahmad4@gmail.com       and for the text ??? there is nothing and instead of $x' in the x-axis= x' \in \mathbb{R^{N-1}}$