# TikZ fails to draw

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, tikz-arrows

I'm trying to use TikZ to draw the following figure, I'm sure that the commands are correct but I obtain the following error:

> "! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/closed' and I
>   am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it."

Can anyone help me with this problem?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing,shapes.geometric}
\colorlet{myred}{red!60!black}
\colorlet{mygreen}{green!40!black}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{units}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[thick,->] (52,0) -- (60,0) node[anchor=north west] {$x'$};
\draw[thick,->] (56,-03) -- (56,03) node[anchor=south east] {$x_N$};
\node[draw=red,dashed,thick,semicircle,minimum width=4cm] (n) at (56,0.8) {};
\node[draw=blue, dashed,thick,semicircle,minimum width=2cm] (n2) at (56,0.4) {};
\node[draw=green,circle,minimum width=4cm] (n3) at (56,0) {};


\draw (56,0) node[below right] {$O$} node{$\bullet$};
\draw (58,0) node[below right] {\color{red} $1$} node{};
\draw (54,0) node[below left] {\color{red} -$1$} node{};
\draw (56.8,0) node[below right] {\color{blue} $r$} node{};
\draw (55.3,0) node[below left] {\color{blue} -$r$} node{};


\draw[red, ->] (n.400) -- +(0.7,0.3) node[pos=1.7]{\color{red} $I^{+}(1)$};
\draw[green, ->] (n3.300) -- +(0.7,-0.3) node[pos=1.5]{\color{green}$I(1)$};
\draw[red, ->] (n.210) -- +(-0.7,-2.3) node[pos=1.2]{\color{red}$\Gamma_1$};
\draw[blue, ->] (n2.320) -- +(0.2,-0.5) node[pos=1.5]{\color{blue}$\Gamma_{r}$};



\node[draw,circle,minimum width=2cm] (n1) at (50,3) {};
\begin{scope}
\clip[draw](48,1) to[closed,curve through={(50,3) -- (52,4) -- (51,6) -- (47,6) -- (46.6,5) -- (45,3.8) }] (48,1);
\node[draw,circle,fill=magenta,minimum width=2cm] (n1) at (50,3) {};
\end{scope}
\node[inner sep=1pt,fill,circle,label={below right: $x_0$}] at (50,3){};
\draw[->,shorten <= -4mm] (n1.90) -- +(0.7,0.7) node[pos=1.3]{$\Omega_1 \cap \Omega$};
\draw[->] (51,6) -- +(0.7,0.3) node[pos=1.3]{$\Omega$};
\draw[->] (n1.300) -- +(0.7,-0.3) node[pos=1.3]{$\Omega_1$};
\draw[->] (n1.10) to[bend left] node[midway,below]{$\tau$} (n.120);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: If you are sure the commands are right, why are you asking us? In that case, it would presumably mean something screwed up with your TeX installation. But why are you so sure they are right?

Comment: Where you find option `closed`? If it exist, than in your MWE is missing some library

Comment: \clip[draw](48,1) to[closed,curve through={(50,3) -- (52,4) -- (51,6) -- (47,6) -- (46.6,5) -- (45,3.8) }] (48,1);    I use the closed here, and i'm sure that it is correct because use the same command with the same figure but with less details. and you can find it here    http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/197094/drawing-a-plane-and-orthonormal-system-using-tikz

Comment: Do you use LuaLateX?

Comment: No, i'm using Texmaker

Comment: Texmaker is editor. LuaLaTeX is version of LaTeX, `closed` in manual is mentioned only  for use with LuaLaTeX, i.e. instead pdfLaTeX try to compile with LuaLaTeX.

Comment: @Zarko It is defined by the Hobby TikZ library.

Comment: Harish Kumar's answer (1) loads the `hobby` library and (2) uses `..` rather than `--` in `curve through`. As noted your discussion there, this depends on a third-party library. `closed` and `curve through` are not provided by regular PGF/TikZ.

Comment: @cfr, Thank you for info. I know for hobby, however never use it (except some test from example on TeX.SE). Unfortunately, `hobby` is not part of TikZ, so it is not mentioned in its manual. There I find only option `close` for use with LuaLaTeX.

Comment: @Zarko I know. I just pinged you in case you were interested. I've only used this for answers here so far, but I found the package intriguing so I looked it up and recognised the `curve through` bit. In any case, the OP knew perfectly well this code required Hobby. That was just omitted from the question, along with any attribution or link to the original code's author.

Answer (score 7):

After answering this, I discovered that the OP already got an answer to this question in the follow-up comments on [Harish Kumar's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/197117/) to an earlier question. In fact, my answer below was perfectly well known to the OP. I'm not certain what the real question here is, but I'm sure it is not the one asked and which I answered.

[Perhaps the question should be, how can this be done without Hobby? Or perhaps it should be, how can I install Hobby? The second would be a duplicate unless there's some specific further problem, of course.]

There are two problems. The first is that you have not loaded the `hobby` library but are trying to use its options. The second is that you cannot use `--` in `curve through`. See the Hobby manual for details.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt,multi]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,hobby}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[thick,->] (52,0) -- (60,0) node[anchor=north west] {$x'$};
  \draw[thick,->] (56,-03) -- (56,03) node[anchor=south east] {$x_N$};
  \node[draw=red,dashed,thick,semicircle,minimum width=4cm] (n) at (56,0.8) {};
  \node[draw=blue, dashed,thick,semicircle,minimum width=2cm] (n2) at (56,0.4) {};
  \node[draw=green,circle,minimum width=4cm] (n3) at (56,0) {};

  \draw (56,0) node[below right] {$O$} node{$\bullet$};
  \draw (58,0) node[below right] {\color{red} $1$} node{};
  \draw (54,0) node[below left] {\color{red} -$1$} node{};
  \draw (56.8,0) node[below right] {\color{blue} $r$} node{};
  \draw (55.3,0) node[below left] {\color{blue} -$r$} node{};

  \draw[red, ->] (n.400) -- +(0.7,0.3) node[pos=1.7]{\color{red} $I^{+}(1)$};
  \draw[green, ->] (n3.300) -- +(0.7,-0.3) node[pos=1.5]{\color{green}$I(1)$};
  \draw[red, ->] (n.210) -- +(-0.7,-2.3) node[pos=1.2]{\color{red}$\Gamma_1$};
  \draw[blue, ->] (n2.320) -- +(0.2,-0.5) node[pos=1.5]{\color{blue}$\Gamma_{r}$};

  \node[draw,circle,minimum width=2cm] (n1) at (50,3) {};
  \begin{scope}
    \clip[draw](48,1) to[closed,curve through={(50,3) .. (52,4) .. (51,6) .. (47,6) .. (46.6,5) .. (45,3.8) }] (48,1);
    \node[draw,circle,fill=magenta,minimum width=2cm] (n1) at (50,3) {};
  \end{scope}
  \node[inner sep=1pt,fill,circle,label={below right: $x_0$}] at (50,3){};
  \draw[->,shorten <= -4mm] (n1.90) -- +(0.7,0.7) node[pos=1.3]{$\Omega_1 \cap \Omega$};
  \draw[->] (51,6) -- +(0.7,0.3) node[pos=1.3]{$\Omega$};
  \draw[->] (n1.300) -- +(0.7,-0.3) node[pos=1.3]{$\Omega_1$};
  \draw[->] (n1.10) to[bend left] node[midway,below]{$\tau$} (n.120);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: hobby code]

Comment: Ok, thank you, but i have a problem in how to use the hobby, when i use hobby i have error.

Comment: when i use the Hobby i get the ollowing error     ! Package tikz Error: I did not find the tikz library 'hobby'. I looked for fil
es named tikzlibraryhobby.code.tex and pgflibraryhobby.code.tex, but neither co
uld be found in the current texmf trees..        @cfr

Comment: So you undid your upvote because my answer points out what you already knew when you asked this question from Harish Kumar i.e. that this depends on Hobby? What did you expect? I now realise that answering this question was pointless because it was not a question to which you wanted to know the answer.

Comment: As I say above, Hobby is a third-party library. Use the package manager provided by your TeX distribution or by your OS if you need to install it. This is just the same for any other package.

Comment: Ok, if i download the Hobby.tex from CTAN do i save it in the same folder of the figure i want to compile? if not how to use it? @cfr

Comment: @Student You should install it with MikTeX's package manager. However, I imagine that putting it into the same directory as you `.tex` file should work. I don't use MikTeX myself.

Comment: can you send to me the pdf file of the figure, i download the hobby.tex and compile and i get the error        "! LaTeX Error: File `expl3.sty' not found".  i try to install it using MiKtex package manager but i get problem report  "Unknown archive file size".  @cfr

Comment: can we draw the figure without using the Hobby-package?

Comment: If you do not have `expl3.sty` then there are 2 possibilities. One is that your installation of TeX is very outdated. (This file is present in TeX Live 2011.) Or you have a quite partial installation of TeX and you've not configured MikTeX for on-the-fly package installation. [A third possibility is that your installation is screwed up, but I'm guessing the very-partial is more likely.]  I recommend asking for help with MikTeX in chat because this is not something I know really anything about. Even if it were TeX Live, I'd be pretty lost on Windows. Unix-like I get. Windows is Mystery Itself.